# How can I insert an error bar with stat_summary() in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I would like to insert an error bar in my diagram. Unfortunately, R draws three error bars on top of each other because the diagram has three instead of only two variables. How can I remove the variable in the legend (the one which defines the shape of the points) from stat_summary()? So that only one error bar for each x-value is drawn?

[image]

```
plot_2 <- ggplot(data = subset(lueftungsverhalten, !is.na(Q17)),
                 aes (x = Q17, y = lueftungsdauer, shape = Q2)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), alpha = 0.4) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, fun.args = list(mult = 1), geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1)
plot_2
```

Comment: Take `shape = Q2` out of `aes` in the main ggplot call and add `aes(shape = Q2)` inside `geom_point`. That way, the layers won't all inherit the `shape` aesthetic, which will also group the summary layers into 3 groups each.